# nutch and sitemap.xml

Tags: search, solr, search-engine, nutch

does apache-nutch support sitemaps?
or how can i implement it myself? how can i use priority field, should it be multiplied to boost field?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.
Depending on the behaviour you expect their are multiple implementations, can u be more specific?
For instance:
+ you can make it that new sitemaps submitted are 'injected' whith a high score so they will get crawled earlier. For this just add an inject command before starting a new crawl/fetch/index cycle
+ you can create a scoring plug-in which will boost URL found in a sitemaps... 
But you can not define recrawl periods at a URL level, as the sitemap would indicate. Nutch has build-in fonction which will recrawl more often URL that changes more an vice-versa. However you could decide to boost score of URL with frequent refresh rate, so that they get crawled earlier...

Answer (score 1):

I guess they support it now. I found it on this link

https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/SitemapFeature